# runtime increases of TVF - decrease after recreation

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got a TVF which returns data of several tables; pseudocode is like:

```
SELECT FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT FROM T2
UNION ALL
SELECT FROM T3
```

Directly after creating this TVF, its runtime is about 30s.
After data modification of one of the base tables took place, runtime explodes and I've to abort the execution of the TVF after 30 minutes and above without result.
**But**: If I **drop** and **recreate** the function, runtime **decreases** to the known 30s.

Any ideas what this is about?

Edit: TVF has no input parameters.

Comment: Did you let it execute only once after data modification? First increase in time consumption may be due to statistics update/new calculation of execution plan; AFAIR second execution should be much faster, or is this also not the case?

Comment: All executions after data modification don't finish in a time interval < 30 min. I cancel the operation at this point, because this execution time is simply too long to work with. Runtime decrease only takes place after drop and create of function.

Comment: Union in very slowly, i prefer use other statment... But for this problem i guess, Add a update statistics in maintenance plan! Schedule for weekly is enough.